# Get informations from user at a Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel

How can I get informations from the user.
I was created an editprofile page when a user wants to change some informations as phone, name and etc.

```
 <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ $user->name }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <label for="surname">Surname</label>
                    <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value="{{ $user->surname }}" class="form-control">
                </div>
```

I want this edited informations to show at the profile page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might solve your problem:

```
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="{{ Auth::user()->name }}" class="form-control">
  <input type="text" id="surname" name="surname" value="{{ Auth::user()->surname }}" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Thank you but I ment to be a view. A user can see the phone, name that entered during registrator.

Comment: To create a view you should go to web.php and add a route for example
Route::get('/editprofile', function () {
    return view('editprofile);});
and create a file in views directory with the same name (editprofile.blade.php)

Comment: For more look at the documentation:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/views#creating-views

Comment: No. I did not mean that. I mean for an example at profile page:

Comment: I mean that for an example: name: users name, phone: users phone. Appearing the information.

Comment: If you have a user phone column in the users table just use the auth function for example  {{ Auth::user()->phoneNumber }}